# Symfony 2: "File" field value is always empty

Tags: symfony

I'm attempting to make a form that builds a slider. It can have any number of images and I'd like to show a preview of already-uploaded images. Getting the multiple image field set up was easy enough, but I'm getting caught up on showing a preview of the image.

I'm using this template to render the "Slider Image" field:

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-widget slider">
        {% set type = type|default('text') %}
        {% if type == 'file' and value is not empty %}
            <img src="{{ value }}" width="200"/><br/>
        {% endif %}
        <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

The `value` variable is always empty on `file` input types, so I'm not sure how I can get at the url of the uploaded images. I am using a custom field type that simply adds a `file` field and hooks up the data source (which is just a simple wrapper around `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`). If you need this code let me know, but its all boilerplate stuff so I doubt you do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your form type look like?

Comment: You want to pre define file input? It's impossible. I'd say it's sesenseless.

Comment: File types have value of local file path. What's the point to set it on server side?

Comment: @Hast: I'm not trying to predefine file input, I'm trying to determine if an image already has been uploaded and if so, present a preview *along with* the file upload widget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symfony2 FileType doesn't have value, its owerwritten in buildView method. 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/FileType.php#L28

But you access it via forms.vars.data

```
    {% if type == 'file' and form.vars.data is not null %}
        {# Here you should somehow generate url to file but let assume 
           you have it in "/path/to/file/" folder that is accessible through web server #}
        <img src="/path/to/file/{{ form.vars.data.name }}" /><br/>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, but instead of `form.vars.data.name` I had to use `form.vars.data.filename`.

Comment: Ahh yes, there is a getFilename method instead of getName :P